# How to speed up downloading data from Quandl/SHARADAR api

Tags: python, concurrency, download, python-asyncio, quandl

I've built a small download manager to get data for the SHARADAR tables in Quandl. [GIT](https://github.com/neilsmurphy/sharadar-download-manager)

This is functioning well but the downloads are very slow for the larger files (up to 2 gb over 10 years).

I attempted to use asyncio but this didn't speed up the downloads. This may be because [Quandl doesn't allow concurrent downloads](https://blog.quandl.com/change-quandl-api-limits). Am I making an error in my code, or is this restriction I will have to live with from Quandl?

```
import asyncio
import math
import time

import pandas as pd
import quandl

import update

def segment_dates(table, date_start, date_end):

    # Determine the number of days per asyncio loop. Determined by the max size of the
    # range of data divided by the size of the files in 100 mb chunks.
    # reduce this number for smaller more frequent downloads.
    total_days = 40

    # Number of days per download should be:
    sizer = math.ceil(total_days / update.sharadar_tables[table][2])

    # Number of days between start and end.
    date_diff = date_end - date_start

    loop_count = int(math.ceil(date_diff.days / sizer))
    sd = date_start
    sync_li = []
    for _ in range(loop_count):
        ed = sd + pd.Timedelta(days=sizer)
        if ed > date_end:
            ed = date_end
        sync_li.append((sd, ed,))
        sd = ed + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

    return sync_li


async def get_data(table, kwarg):
    """
    Using the table name and kwargs retrieves the most current data.
    :param table: Name of table to update.
    :param kwarg: Dictionary containing the parameters to send to Quandl.
    :return dataframe: Pandas dataframe containing latest data for the table.
    """
    return quandl.get_table("SHARADAR/" + table.upper(), paginate=True, **kwarg)


async def main():

    table = "SF1"

    # Name of the column that has the date field for this particular table.
    date_col = update.sharadar_tables[table][0]

    date_start = pd.to_datetime("2020-03-15")
    date_end = pd.to_datetime("2020-04-01")

    apikey = "API Key"
    quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = apikey

    # Get a list containing the times start and end for loops.
    times = segment_dates(table, date_start, date_end)

    wait_li = []
    for t in times:
        kwarg = {date_col: {"gte": t[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), "lte": t[1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}}
        wait_li.append(loop.create_task(get_data(table, kwarg)))

    await asyncio.wait(wait_li)
    return wait_li

if __name__ == "__main__":
    starter = time.time()
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        res = loop.run_until_complete(main())
        for r in res:
            df = r.result()
            print(df.shape)
            print(df.head())
    except:
        raise ValueError("error")
    finally:
        # loop.close()

    print("Finished in {}".format(time.time() - starter))
```

Comment: The information you provided indicates that the download speed is limited by the server at the other end.  There is nothing you can possibly do in your program to solve this problem.  You can bet that your program is already doing nothing most of the time, waiting for data to arrive on the network.  The only thing you can accomplish with asyncio, or threading, or multiprocessing is to make it spend more energy doing nothing.

Comment: OK, I suspected as much, thanks @Pa